# number formatting mask for to_char()

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Can you explain the difference between the following queries

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1980.55,'$9,999D999') FROM DUAL;
```

and

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(1980.55,'$9G999D999') FROM DUAL;
```

The first query fails with an error, what I don't understand is that the group separator defaults to ',' so why does one fail and the other execute successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting, haven't come across that before, but then can't imagine why you'd want to mix them. I can't find anything in the documentation or even on MSO, so I'll speculate...

The ORA-01481 error you get from mixing comma/period with the group separator/decimal characters (`G` or `D`) is 'invalid number format model', which suggests it's purely validating the string `'$9,999D999'`. It appears that at this stage it is not aware of your `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTER` setting, even if it's passed in to the `to_char()` function as the optional third argument. That doesn't seem too unreasonable since the same validation would apply in stored code (procedure, package, view or whatever), and you wouldn't expect a cached query to be revalidated based on the NLS settings (i.e. a hard parse).

So if at the point that format model string is validated it doesn't know how `G` and `D` will be evaluated at runtime, the [restrictions listed in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C) become a problem. Is your comma supposed to be a group separator or a decimal character? If at run-time your decimal character is `.` then the format would be invalid as you can only have one of those. Similarly if the model was `'9.999G999'` then it would be valid if your group separator is `.`, but not if it is `,`. Failing at parse time rather than run time seems safer and more reliable.

Or to put it another way, the point where 'the group separator defaults to `,`' is *after* the format model has been validated, so it doesn't make any difference.

But, as I say, speculating on the internals, which is never a very good idea. The documentation seems to be a bit misleading when it says a 'comma [or group separator] cannot appear to the right of a decimal character or period in a number format model', since it they can't coexist at all. Might be worth raising a documentation bug?

---

A similar issue was raised as bug 1204892 against 8i, and closed as not-a-bug with comment 'This is the way it's designed to work'.

Comment: Ha ha I like the comment 'This is the way it's designed to work'. I think it really adds up now :-)